# What is the difference between dimension and length of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
A=np.full([63,51,121], 0.0)
print (A)
A.ndim
len(A)
```

I am confused between the dimension and length of the Array A. I thought array A is an array of 63 matrices of order 51x121.The first index .i.e. 63, refers to the number of dimensions? Upon further researching i stumbled on commands , len. and ndim.
Length commands give me 63 as response but ndim tells it is a 3 dimensional array. I am quite new to the computer programming, If my array is 3D, how to create one with more than 3 Dimension in contrast to see and compare the difference. How can one visualize such arrays and more over how is the indexing and slicing is done in such cases.

Comment: `A=np.full([63,51,121,375,2], 0.0)` will make a 5d array.  Don't try to 'visualize'..  `A.shape` is the most useful descriptor.  Indexing and slices is just  generalization of the 1d and 2d versions.

Comment: Have you read the beginner's guide?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html   `shape`, dimensions, visualization (or not) are all covered there.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to [`np.full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) is `shape`, which defines the length of each dimension of the np array.

Under the hood, three-dimensional shaped objects in numpy are nested arrays-within-arrays, so the value `[63,51,121]` for `shape` will give you an outer array with a length of 63, each element of which is a nested array of length 51, of which each element is further nested array of 121 `0.0`s.

---

This is why `A.ndim` gives you 3 - A is a 3D object, yet the `len` (length) of the outer array is 63.

Try running `A.shape`, or `len(A[0])`, which will hopefully let you see how things are working.